'_RestrictData' error on addon's register()
Quite often I use Gstretch tool from the LoopTools standard extension.
The default value for the Gstretch guides is None :
___

____
*There is NO situation when None value is useful.
And I'm highly annoyed that after every Blender's restart I should manually change None to Annotation (my preferred option)
So I made a simple addon, which automatically sets this value to Annotation on addon's register():
bl_info = {
    "name": "Set Gstretch",
    "version": (0, 0, 1),
    "blender": (4, 2, 2),
    "description": "Set 'Annotation' as a guide for looptools' Gstretch",
    "category": "MyPrefs",
}


def register():
    import bpy
    bpy.data.window_managers["WinMan"].looptools.gstretch_use_guide = 'Annotation'

def unregister():
    pass


But on every register() addon fails with an error:
RuntimeError: Error: '_RestrictData' object has no attribute 'window_managers'


I thought this error emerges because window_managers are not fully loaded when addon registers.
But when we install the addon in minutes after blender started - this error also emerges.
(!)Hence the suggestion (about window_managers not being loaded) is false.

Two questions:

What causes this error ?

How can I bypass this error ?




Access _RestrictData when blender runs the registration level code
import bpy, _bpy

def register():
    print(_bpy.data.objects)

1. What causes this error ?
The reason for this error is that blender deliberately restricted the access rights of bpy. to avoid some errors
2. How can I bypass this error ?
See top

If your add-on needs to access data from another add-on in register function, you may consider delaying registration to ensure that the add-on is registered first.
How can I run a function when opening Blender that requires context?

Many thanks for your comprehensive answer! ❤️
